# Casting object and use all overrides method without if statement

Tags: java, casting

Here my simple Class Diagram

https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-2Sgqhmq4o_I/TfeQ2KeJiYI/AAAAAAAAAaw/RhIqPGynYhY/s800/ClassDiagram1.jpg

```
    if (exit.isPressed()) {
        stop();
    }

    //I want to casting this Sprite depent on their subclass
    Sprite temp=map.getPlayer(); //This return Sprite object

    //like this:
    if(temp instanceof Bisona)
      Bison player=(Bison) map.getPlayer();
    else
      SuperBison player=(SuperBison) map.getPlayer();

    if(message==PLAYING){
        //I got error on this line
        //I know why i got that error. Coz i dont declare player.
        //And java don't know what player object exactly? is Bison/SuperBison 
        if (player.isAlive() && player.getState()==Sprite.STATE_NORMAL) {
            float velocityX = 0;
            if (moveLeft.isPressed()) {
                velocityX-=player.getMaxSpeed();
            }
            if (moveRight.isPressed()) {
                velocityX+=player.getMaxSpeed();
            }
            if (jump.isPressed()) {
                //My aim is to call this line without if that object
                player.jump(false);
            }
            if (attack.isPressed()){
                //My aim is to call this line without if that object
                player.attack();
            }
            player.setVelocityX(velocityX);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Set Velocity to zero
        player.setVelocityX(0);
    }
```

Is that possible to do that?

Thanks

Sorry for my bad english :D

Comment: I don't understand the question (or title).

Comment: What error message do you exactly get?
Why do you want to cast to Bizon/SuperBizon anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, Bison and SuperBison have the same methods. Then you simply cast you player to Bison, and call the Bison methods.

You seem to misunderstand casting. In Java, casting (for reference types) never changes the type of an object, it only changes what the compiler thinks of an object reference.
The object still stays the same, and on runtime the VM actually checks that this is really a fitting object.

Here

```
if(temp instanceof JabangTetuka) {
  Bison player=(Bison) map.getPlayer();
}
else {
  SuperBison player=(SuperBison) map.getPlayer();
}
```

You are creating two `player` variables of different types, which each are only valid in the surrounding `{...}` blocks. (Even if you did not had the braces in your code, the blocks are still there.)

Thus you can't use the variable at all.

If your player already is a Bison, then you can simply write

```
Bison player = (Bison) map.getPlayer();
```

But I somehow doublt that your player will be all of Sprite, JabangTetuka and Bison, or you have a really strange inheritance relation.

Comment: I have mistyped "JabangTetuka" should Bison.

Comment: If so, since SuperBison is a subclass of Bison, your second cast would never succeed (apart from `null`, which is castable but gives `false` in `instanceof` checks).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough code here to determine whether you have done this, but the following must be true to get the desired behavior:

1. Bison and Super Bison must inherit or extend from a common class.
2. The common class must define, at least abstractly, the methods that Bison and SuperBison share.
3. Bison and SuperBison must override the common class's methods.
4. The 'player' variable you are using should be of the common class's type.

With these things met, polymorphism should be on your side.

Answer (score 0):

Your object `player` is declared within the scope of the `if` statement and no longer exists where you call `player.isAlive()`. Also, according to your diagram, none of the classes in the inheritance tree define `isAlive()` or `getState()`

Also, as DJ Quimby states, your `Creature` class could define the methods you want to call and you can override them in `Bison` and `SuperBison` to give them their specific functionality.